# RatingBar and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ratingbar

I am trying to make an application that rates 8 different types of foods with simple rater and recyclerview. Pressing the FAB button just adds a random food with 0 rating. I have gotten most of it to work except the rating of the rating bar. When I scroll up or down, I lose the ratings I had. How can I store the ratings of food when I scroll up or down.

RecyclerView:

```
package com.mycompany.alawamhm.foodrater;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.icu.text.AlphabeticIndex;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;


public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private Random mRandom = new Random();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
final HashMap<String,Integer> defaultName;
final ArrayList<String> mNames=new ArrayList<>();

public FoodAdapter(RecyclerView rv){
    defaultName = new HashMap<>();
    defaultName.put("banana", R.drawable.banana);
    defaultName.put("broccoli", R.drawable.broccoli);
    defaultName.put("homemade bread", R.drawable.bread);
    defaultName.put("chicken", R.drawable.chicken);
    defaultName.put("chocolate", R.drawable.chocolate);
    defaultName.put("ice cream", R.drawable.icecream);
    defaultName.put("lima beans", R.drawable.limabeans);
    defaultName.put("steak", R.drawable.steak);
    for(String name : defaultName.keySet()){
        mNames.add(name);
    }
    mRecyclerView = rv;

}

public String getRandomName(){
    String[] names = new String[]{
            "banana","broccoli","homemade bread","chicken",
            "chocolate","ice cream","lima beans","steak"
    };
    return names[mRandom.nextInt(names.length)];
}

public void addName(){
    mNames.add(0,getRandomName());
    notifyItemInserted(0);
    mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
}

@Override
public FoodAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.name_view,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String name = mNames.get(position);
    holder.mNameTextView.setText(name);
    holder.mImage.setImageResource(defaultName.get(name));
    holder.rBar.setRating(0);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return mNames.size(); }


public void removeName(int position){
    mNames.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView mNameTextView;
    private ImageView mImage;
    SimpleRatingBar rBar;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mNameTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_view);
        mImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        rBar = (SimpleRatingBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The check should only return the number if the key (food) matches, otherwise it should return 0. Right now it sounds like it's returning the rating whether the key matches or not...... Also, these ratings will only exist while the app is running. Once the app is closed the hashMap will clear. If you want to keep the data you'll need to store it in SharedPreferences or a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the ratings bar is being set to 0 every time a view is bound to a view holder. Set a listener on the rating bar that runs a method to store the new rating value in a hashSet. Then in the adapter, instead of setting the rating bar to 0, add a helper method that iterates through the hashMap to check if a value has been stored for the food being inflated. This method should return the stored value or 0 if the food hasn't stored a value yet.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! However, now all the same foods have the same rating, any idea how I can possibly fix that?

Comment: So it does return the value when it matches, but because the keys(food) repeats, I think they all end up having the same rating because they share the same key. For example, if I rate chocolate 3, then by adding another chocolate randomly, it would set it to 3 stars by default because the key (chocolate) already exists and has 3 stars.

Comment: It sounds like the helper method is returning the stored value whether the current food matches a food in the hashMap. The helper method should only return the rating for the current view if the current food matches a key (food) in the hashMap, otherwise it should return 0.

Comment: The key for each food will have to be unique and added as such... for example the key for chocolate shouldn't be food. It should be chocolate. Basically, add to hashMap as " 'chocolate' , '3' ". If another chocolate is randomly added, it will need a unique key name as well, like chocolate2.

Comment: Also, it's important to know that the data will not be kept once the app closes. To keep the data you'll need to store it in SharedPreferences or a database.